# How to create a type using variables for the keys

Tags: typescript, react-navigation

I am trying to re-create this type for react navigation route params:

```
export type RootStackParamList = {
  "Welcome": undefined;
  "Onboarding User": { category: string };
}
```

But instead of a string as the key, using a variable like below

```
interface path { [key: string]: string }

export const PATHS: path = {
  welcome: 'Welcome',
  onboardingUser: "Onboarding User",
};


export type RootStackParamList = {
  [PATHS.welcome]: undefined;
  [PATHS.onboardingUser]: { category: string };
}
```

Error received is `TS1170: A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.`

How can I create an interface with a variable that does not change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found the answer as I posted the question.

Rather than using a const for PATHS that the interface uses, I changed it to an enum.

```
export enum PATHS {
  welcome = 'Welcome',
  onboardingUser = "Onboarding User"
};


export type RootStackParamList = {
  [PATHS.welcome]: undefined;
  [PATHS.onboardingUser]: { category: string };
}
```